# How to parse different parts of a string into separate variables?

Tags: ada

How do I get "IL" then saving it to TempCode which is a string and so on to giving each word, integer and float a Temporary variable. Then get the next TempCode and so on. The whole point is to get a certain code under Code Column then do that operation and get the Department, Name/Vendor,Title,ID and Payrate to be use.

```
    with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
    with GNAT.String_Split; use GNAT.String_Split;
    
    procedure TextFile is
       File   : File_Type;
   Tokens : Slice_Set;
   --Index : Slice_Number;
   TempCode: String := "";
begin
   Open (File, In_File, "DynList.txt");
   -- Skip the file header
   Skip_Line (File);
   -- Read the data
   while not End_Of_File (File) loop
      -- Split the line from the file on array which contains separated
      -- words. Treat multiple spaces as a single separator (don't
      -- create empty elements).
      Create (Tokens, Get_Line (File), " ", Multiple);
      -- Print each of the array's values
      for I in 1 .. Slice_Count (Tokens) loop
--I have try using function Separators 
         Put_Line (Slice (Tokens, I));
      end loop;

   end loop;

   Close (File);
    end TextFile;
```

Store.txt

```
Code    Department  Name/Vendor  Title          ID      Payrate
IL      Sales       John         Sales_person   1378    25.46
IR      Crew        Jesse        Sales_person   1379    25.46
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you want to define a type for your payrate.  A float will work, but I would recommend making a fixed point type instead as it prints cleaner for what you want.

```ada
type Payrate_Type is delta 0.01 range 0.00 .. 1000.00;
```

To read in values for your type, you will need to instantiate the generic Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO:

```ada
package Payrate_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO(Payrate_Type);
```

Next I would group all your variables for each field in a single record.  Use Unbounded_String to store the strings, Natural for the ID, and your pay rate type for your pay rate.

```ada
type Line_Info is record
    Code       : Unbounded_String;
    Department : Unbounded_String;
    Name       : Unbounded_String;
    Title      : Unbounded_String;
    ID         : Natural;
    Payrate    : Payrate_Type;
end record;

A_Line : Line_Info;
```

Then for each iteration of your while loop, instead of the for loop, you just do individual assignments for each of the various slice pieces:

```ada
A_Line.Code       := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 1));
A_Line.Department := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 2));
A_Line.Name       := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 3));
A_Line.Title      := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 4));
A_Line.ID         := Natural'Value(Slice(Tokens, 5));
Payrate_IO.Get(Slice(Tokens,6),A_Line.Payrate,Last);
```

You'll need to do some exception handling logic to cover when your input is not correct.  I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Here's a test program for your input set:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.String_Split; use GNAT.String_Split;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
    
procedure Hello is
    Tokens : Slice_Set;
    --Index : Slice_Number;
    TempCode: String := "";
    
    type Payrate_Type is delta 0.01 range 0.00 .. 1000.00;
    
    type Line_Info is record
        Code       : Unbounded_String;
        Department : Unbounded_String;
        Name       : Unbounded_String;
        Title      : Unbounded_String;
        ID         : Natural;
        Payrate    : Payrate_Type;
    end record;
    
    A_Line : Line_Info;
    
    package Payrate_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO(Payrate_Type);
    
    Last : Positive;
    
begin
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");
    Skip_Line;
    -- Read the data
    while not End_Of_File loop
        -- Split the line from the file on array which contains separated
        -- words. Treat multiple spaces as a single separator (don't
        -- create empty elements).
        Create (Tokens, Get_Line, " ", Multiple);
        -- Print each of the array's values
        
        A_Line.Code       := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 1));
        A_Line.Department := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 2));
        A_Line.Name       := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 3));
        A_Line.Title      := To_Unbounded_String(Slice(Tokens, 4));
        A_Line.ID         := Natural'Value(Slice(Tokens, 5));
        Payrate_IO.Get(Slice(Tokens,6),A_Line.Payrate,Last);
        
        Put_Line(To_String(A_Line.Code));
        Put_Line(To_String(A_Line.Department));
        Put_Line(To_String(A_Line.Name));
        Put_Line(To_String(A_Line.Title));
        Put_Line(A_Line.ID'Image);
        Put_Line(A_Line.Payrate'Image);

    end loop;
end Hello;
```

And the output:

```
$gnatmake -o hello *.adb
gcc -c hello.adb
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatlink hello.ali -o hello
$hello
Hello, world!
IL
Sales
John
Sales_person
 1378
 25.46
IR
Crew
Jesse
Sales_person
 1379
 25.46
```

Note that I took out your File type and calls so I could test really quick using standard in as the input source.

Comment: You may want to use a decimal fixed-point type here instead of an ordinary fixed-point type. Ordinary fixed-point types (without an explicitly defined value for the `Small` attribute) will get you into trouble when doing multiplication and division later on (try computing e.g. `10 * 25.46` using type `Payrate_Type` and check the result). Decimal fixed-point types were added to [Ada 95](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-3.html#3-3) to address these issues when processing financial data.